# Access jstl variable in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Im populating customer data by iterating a customer list as following in the jsp.

```
<form action="CustomerUpdate" method="post">
<c:forEach var="listItems" items="${customers}">          
   <label> First Name: </label><c:out value="${listItems.fname}" />  
   <label> Last Name: </label><c:out value="${listItems.lname}" />
   <label> Address: </label><c:out value="${listItems.address}" /> &nbsp;
   <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
   <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"><br />     
</c:forEach> 
</form>
```

Now in the action either edit or delete each record i want to track which customer needs to be edit/delete. So in servlet how can i access the customer object which is in var listItems. If its not possible do i need to have hidden input variables with values and access them using getParameter in servlet?

Answer (score 3):

This is only a simple example on how to do it. Change your code in this way:

```
<c:forEach var="listItems" items="${customers}">          
  <form action="CustomerUpdate" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="${listItems.id}" name="id">
    <label> First Name: </label><c:out value="${listItems.fname}" />  
    <label> Last Name: </label><c:out value="${listItems.lname}" />
    <label> Address: </label><c:out value="${listItems.address}" /> &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="action">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action"><br />     
  </form>
</c:forEach>
```

**Update**

Create a form element for every row, and put for every row an hidden field with the `id`.
So when you press that button you will receive in the request a value that make you able to detect the row. In this way:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String action = request.getParameter("action");
```

Now you know the `id` and the `action` type (edit or delete).

**Alternative solution**

Do not use the form and submit to call your action, but use a direct link.

```
<c:forEach var="listItems" items="${customers}">          
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="id">
  <label> First Name: </label><c:out value="${listItems.fname}" />  
  <label> Last Name: </label><c:out value="${listItems.lname}" />
  <label> Address: </label><c:out value="${listItems.address}" /> &nbsp;
  <button onclick="window.location.href='CustomerUpdate?action=edit&id=${listItems.id}'">Edit</button>
  <button onclick="window.location.href='CustomerUpdate?action=delete&id=${listItems.id}'">Delete</button>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: the problem here is the edit button shows the first name too with Edit. So i have tried <button name="action" value="Edit-${listItems.fname}" type="submit">Edit</button>. But when i access it using request.getParameter("action") it returns the value as Edit not the value in the value attribute

Comment: Ok I updated my answer with a new suggestion. However there are many different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

in the **servlet** check the which button was clicked as:

```
if (request.getParameter("action") != null) //if action is not null
        {
            String action = request.getParameter("action");
String id = request.getParameter("id");

            if (action.equals("edit")) //edit button clicked
            {
               //do your work here
            }
            else if (action.equals("delete")) //delete button clicked
            {
                //your work here
            }
}
```